Absolute convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(\frac{\cos(n)}{\ln(n^{2n}+n^2)}+1-\cos(\frac{1}{n}))$
I have shown the convergence of the series by using Dirichlet's test to show that the first summand $\frac{\cos(n)}{\ln(n^{2n}+n^2)}$ converge and the comparison test to show that $1-\cos(\frac{1}{n})$ converge, but I am struggling to determine its absolute convergence.
Initially, I attempted the comparison:
$$
\left|\frac{\cos(n)}{\ln(n^{2n}+n^2)}+1-\cos\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)\right| \le\frac{\left|\cos(n)\right|}{\ln(n^{2n}+n^2)}+1-\cos\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)
$$
However, I found that the right-hand side diverges since $\frac{|\cos(n)|}{\ln(n^{2n}+n^2)}$ diverges.
Can someone guide me on how to test for absolute convergence in this case? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

You may erase the $1- \cos \frac{1}{n}$ as that sum converges. Next, $\log (n^{2n}  + n^2)$  is not distinguishable from $2n \log n.$   So, what about sum of $\frac{|\cos n |}{2 n \log n} ?$  My first impression is that $|\cos n| \geq \frac{1}{2}$  a positive proportion of the time

I don't know if it'll help and it's just a suggestion. How about Abu-Mostafa's test?

Vaskara_GRek_O, interesting, i haven't heard about it. although i'm not sure how to construct a function such that f(1/n)=an which is defined at 0

Let $x_n:=\frac{\cos n}{\ln(n^{2n}+n^2)}$ and $y_n:=1-\cos\frac1n$. You already found that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n$ converge and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x_n|$ diverges.
Since $y_n\ge0$, the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n$ is absolute. Since that of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ is not, neither is that of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(x_n+y_n)$.

thank you. can you explain why does the fact that xn is not absolutely convergent imply that neither is xn+yn?

By contradiction and because if $\sum z_n$ and $\sum y_n$ are absolutely convergent then so is $\sum(z_n-y_n)$.

thank you very much.

Note that $\left| \tfrac{\cos n}{\log (n^{2n}+n^2)} + 1-\cos \tfrac{1}{n}\right|\leq \left|\tfrac{\cos n}{2n\log n}\right|+\left|1-\cos \tfrac{1}{n}\right|$.
Using the Taylor expansion of $\cos x$ around $0$, it is not difficult to see that $\left|1-\cos \tfrac{1}{n}\right|$ bounded above and below by constant times $\tfrac
{1}{n^2}$, so the second summand definitely converges.
However, $\sum_{n\geq 1} \tfrac{|\cos n|}{n\log n}$ diverges, see for example Convergence of $\sum\frac{|\cos n|}{n\log n}$
